# How to specify `node_modules` from parent folder in `serverless.yml`?

Tags: serverless

In `serverless.yml` file, how can I include the modules from parent folder?

```
package:
  include:
    - ../node_modules/**
```

but the packaged zip file doesn't include the dependencies from parent `node_modules` folder. I have tried  the plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-plugin-include-dependencies but it still doesn't work. None of dependencies from parent folder is packaged.

How can I change the dependencies folder directory when packaging my application? I also want to apply excluding `devDependencies` logic for the parent folder.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to package your functions individually in some side script & then run the serverless deploy.

Then you can easily fine-tune your packaging process and include the node_modules from your parent, excluding the dev dependencies.

```
package:
  individually: true

functions:
  sample:
    package:
      artifact: ../functions/sample/deploy/sample.zip
```

Another small benefit on this is, if you only want to update some function you can explicitly just repackage that one and run the serverless deploy much faster.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will have to manage to exclude devDependencies in this script which is a bit complicated. I am prefer to leverage the feature of serverless as much as possible.

Comment: I understand that! Keep it simple is always a good idea. What else came to my mind: would it probably make sense to make use of a lambda layer? Especially if you got a lot of lambda functions with almost equal dependencies, this makes a lot of sense and is also easily doable with serverless.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. I had a directory structure that looked like:

```
myproject/
  src/
    serverless.yml
    ...
  node_modules/
    ...
```

Make sure that you're running the `serverless` command from the `src/` directory, not from the root `myproject/` directory.

Then, when declaring my function, in serverless.yml it looks like:

```
myFunc:
  handler: handlers/my_func.update
  package:
    include:
      - ../node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-athena/**
      - ../node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-ssm/**
      - ../node_modules/axios/**
      - ../node_modules/googleapis/**
```

Earlier, I also screwed up because I had something like this, but it wasn't including anything as well:

```
myFunc:
  handler: handlers/my_func.update
  package:
    include:
      - ../node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-athena  <-- missing /** at the end!
      - ../node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-ssm     <-- missing /** at the end!
      - ../node_modules/axios                   <-- missing /** at the end!
      - ../node_modules/googleapis              <-- missing /** at the end!
```

I hope those hints help you (or someone else).